# How to specify a range of repetitions in Scala's parser combinators?

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

Scala's parser combinators allow to specify some repetitions as 0 or more (`.*`), 1 or more (`.+`), etc. Is it possible to specify a range? For example, `rep(p, q)(parser)` where parser is run at least `p` times and up to `q` times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Combinator Operations in Scala's Parser Combinators are roughly modeled after [*Regular Expressions*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_definition). Regular Expressions only have three Combinator Operations:

Given two Regular Expressions `R` and `S`,

- `RS` is a Regular Expression (*Concatenation*)
- `R | S` is a Regular Expression (*Alternation*)
- `R*` is a Regular Expression (*Kleene Star*)

That's it. Scala adds a couple more, most notably `+` and `?` but that doesn't actually increase the power since `R+` is actually just `RR*` and `R?` is just `R | ε`. The same applies to your proposed `rep` combinator. It does not actually increase the power since

```
R{m, n}
```

is actually just

```
RRRRRRRRRRR(ε | R | RR | RRR | RRRR | RRRRR | RRRRRR | RRRRRRR | RRRRRRRR | RRRRRRRRR)
 ↑↑ m×R ↑↑                                                                ↑↑ (m-n)×R ↑↑
```

Now, of course, while this doesn't increase the *power* of the Parsers, it *does* increase the expressivity and thus readability and maintainability.

It would be pretty easy to build it on top of `|` and `repN`, I believe.

Something like:

```scala
/** A parser generator for a number of repetitions within a range.
 *
 *  `repMN(m, n, p)` uses `p` between `m` and `n` time to parse the input
 *  (the result is a `List` of the consecutive results of `p`).
 *
 * @param p   a `Parser` that is to be applied successively to the input
 * @param min the minimum number of times `p` must succeed
 * @param max the maximum number of times `p` must succeed
 * @return    A parser that returns a list of results produced by repeatedly applying `p` to the input
 *        (and that only succeeds if `p` matches between `m` and `n` times).
 */
def repMN[T](min: Int, max: Int, p: ⇒ Parser[T]) = 
  (min to max).reverse map { repN(_, p) } reduce {_ | _}
```

This looks useful enough that it might even make sense to file as an enhancement request.

Comment: Yes, it totally makes sense. Thank you for this detailed answer!

Comment: repNM was integrated to the lib. waiting for a release.

Comment: Very nice! Congratulations!